# Groups such that all finite-dim representations are finitely presented

Tags: gr.group-theory, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be an infinite group.  What sorts of finiteness properties can I put on $G$ to ensure the following holds for all $M$?

Let $M$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ upon which $G$ acts.  Then $M$ is a finitely presentable $\mathbb{Q}[G]$ module.

Comment: This holds if $G$ is finitely generated: indeed you get a finite presentation by picking a basis of $M$ as generators and the images by group generators of the basis elements as relators.